# Export specs descriptions as comments in the source file

Tags: javascript, jasmine, gulp, karma-runner

Is it possible to export jasmine specs descriptions back to the original source file as comments above the functions that were tested? I'm using `karma-runner` launched via gulp.

```
it("has a positive case ", function() {
    expect(someFunction()).toBe(true);
});
```

I would like to automatically write the descriptions back in the source code as shown bellow, and see them picked-up by the documentation tool.

```
/* @desc has a positive case */
someFunction() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not easy as you think, there are some edge cases you need to decide about. for e.g what if your test is like this:

```
it("some combination test", function() {
  expect(someFunction()).toBe(true);
  expect(anotherFunction()).toBe(false)
});
```

In this case what should happen? do you need the description to be inserted for both function in the source?

Comment: I agree, it's not pretty to encounter a situation like that. But I think a manual process of configuring which strings go back to source at which exact label and wich ones to skip would be sufficient as long as I don't have to manually update changed descriptions or deleted ones. I guess this job would be done by a third party tool. I am aware that `it()` returns the description string. So collecting them is doable. But I don't know how to pass them into the source file at the correct location.

Comment: you use gulp ? grunt?

Comment: Gulp (and karma-runner for tests, just mentioning)